# Pydoc ignores opencv function, just considers python functions defined with def keyword

Tags: python, opencv, contour, pydoc

I want to develop API documentation for my OpenCV project.

But when I ran `pydoc - w` command on my module, it only created  documentation for those function which are declared with the def key word.

Pydoc ignores OpenCV functions like `cv2.videocaputure()`. They are not included in the documentation.

```
def initState(A, B, C, D, E, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5):
    """if all blocks are there and good recognized, if not shows message.
        :param: The number of objects
        :type: int
         :putText()
         :return: intial state top or initial state reconized with all objects,
                  show text on window Sorry , objects not recognized(Text)
     """
    if (A == 1 and B == 1 and C == 1 and D == 1 and E == 1 and P1 == 1 and P2 == 1 and P3 == 1 and P4 == 1 and P5 == 1):

        cv2.putText(frame, "initial state top",
                    (100, 100), font, 1, (0, 0, 255))
    else:
        cv2.putText(frame, "Sorry, not recognized",
                    (100, 100), font, 1, (0, 0, 255))
# knowing if final state is completed, must be recognized in the moment, if not recognized nothing will be shown


def finalState(A, B, C, D, E, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5):
    """knowing if final state is completed, must be recognized in the moment, if not recognized nothing will be shown.
    :param: The number of objects
    :type: int
    :putText()
    :return: Final state reconized with all objects(Text),
    """
    if (A == 1 and B == 1 and C == 1 and D == 1 and E == 1 and P1 == 1 and P2 == 1 and P3 == 1 and P4 == 1 and P5 == 1):

        cv2.putText(frame, "final state top", (100, 100), font, 1, (0, 0, 255))
        return 1


# capturing video, if want to change file or do it with a web cam just change the value
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('exp11111.mp4')
"""
    This will simply create the object
    for the camera and using this object we can control the
    video capturing and other functions related to the web cam.
    :param: can be either the device index or the name of a video file
"""

# starting while loop to recognize every frame.
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if(
            ret == False):
        break

    """
     Capture frame-by-frame
    :return: bool (True,False)
    
    
    """
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce.

I took your code and faked `cv.py`

```py
class VideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def read(self):
        pass

def putText(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

And then ran:

```sh
python -m pydoc -w your_code
```

And I got `cap = <cv2.VideoCapture object>` in the output.

If you want do also generate documents for cv2, you will need:

```sh
python -m pydoc -w cv2
```

It is hard to get pydoc to do what you want without either [forking](https://github.com/matthewdeanmartin/pydoc_fork) it or switching to one of the many better alternatives, e.g. pdoc3, pydoctor, or pycco.